# Setting Origin and Upstream in Gitkraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

I've been working on a Mac using Sourcetree to manage my repositories. I've recently found an Ubuntu machine to develop on, and having found that Sourcetree isn't available for Ubuntu, found Gitkraken as a potential alternative.

My question is, is there any way to set a different remote repository in Gitkraken for pushes and pulls? (E.g. push to origin/develop pull from upstream/develop using the buttons on the top menubar). And if that isn't possible, is there a way to track a different remote branch from the one you are pushing/pulling from?

For example Sourcetree is set up so that local/develop tracks the remote branch upstream/develop, while pushing to the remote branch origin/develop. So if people make changes to the original repository, it'll show up in my Sourcetree and I'll know to pull from upstream/develop to local/develop. And if I make any changes, I can push my fork at origin/develop and create a pull request there to merge to upstream/develop if the changes are approved.

Also, in in Gitkraken if I right click upstream/develop there is an option to `merge upstream/develop into develop` that should take the most recent changes in upstream/develop and merge it into my local copy right? (God help me if suddenly I'm merging my local develop to upstream).

Comment: +1 for this feature, I sent them email asking for this. Its very useful especially working with forking flow on OS projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, is there any way to set a different remote repository
>   in Gitkraken for pushes and pulls?

There is no such feature AFAIK. When right-clicking a branch, you can select to `Set Upstream`. This results in the message `What remote/branch should "<branch>" push to an pull from?`, which implies that a branch can only be set to push and pull from the same upstream via GitKraken.

> [...] is there a way to track a different remote branch from the one you are
>   pushing/pulling from?

I do not understand what you mean by "track" here, since a branch tracking an upstream means it is using it to pull from and/or push to. As per definition [here in section `Tracking Branches`](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches), upstream and tracking branch are used synonymous, so I guess the answer is no:

> [...]what is called a “tracking branch” (or sometimes an “upstream branch”).

Concerning your last question, you can calm down:

> [...]if I right click upstream/develop there is an option to `merge upstream/develop into develop` that should take the most recent changes
>   in upstream/develop and merge it into my local copy right?

That's exactly what it does, just like a `git merge upstream/develop` when you have checked out your local `develop`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Kinda sucks that there isn't a way to have a branch tracking different push/pull locations, but its nice getting some clarification on what the merge upstream/develop into develop does. I guess if I ever want to track the changes made to upstream I'll just have to manually set upstream every single time.

Comment: Also a workaround I guess is that you can have your develop branch track upstream, but have any other feature branches tracking origin which in essence does what I want it to.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know how recently it is possible, but in version 6.0.0 of GitKraken, you can right-click on an origin and change push and pull paths independently.

[image: screenshot]